# how I can have the following value using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a problem to retrieve the following value for the time I retrieve the first value in the database using this code

```
revision_csharpContainer premier = new revision_csharpContainer();
etudiant et = premier.etudiants.First();
comboBox1.Text = et.id_etudiant.ToString();
textBox1.Text = et.Nom;
textBox2.Text = et.prenom;
textBox3.Text = et.age.ToString();
comboBox2.Text = et.filiere.filiere1;
textBox4.Text = et.photo;
```

but I want when I click the following button I get the next value from the database

Comment: Write a `revision_csharpContainer.Next()`. We won't be able to give a much better answer without knowing the code/database/API involved.

Answer (score 0):

> but I want when I click the following button I get the next value from
>   the database

You could use `Skip(1).First()` to get the next

```
etudiant next = premier.etudiants.Skip(1).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid multiple enumerations, you can get an enumerator and work through that.

```
IEnumerator<etudiant> enumerator = premier.etudiants.GetEnumerator();
```

The code that will retrieve the first item and any subsequent items will be identical:

```
if (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    etudiant et = enumerator.Current;
    comboBox1.Text = et.id_etudiant.ToString();
    // etc...
}
```